# Set Page Setup properties into ReportViewer

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

How to set Page Setup properties: Orientation, Margins of a Report in ReportViewer using vb2012 code,  in a vb2012 aplication
Thank you for any help

Comment: do you want to set it only through code?

Comment: if you just want to set the properties(Not Programmatically), then you can do this      
`Right click on report.rdlc[Desing] file -->  click report properties --> change the page orientation and resize the report.`

Comment: I wanted to do it by code Thanks

Comment: But where do I find click report properties --> change the page orientation
wherever I click there's no change the page orientation

Comment: Hey Antony Did you check my answer. Is it working for you. Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `PageSettings object`, set the properties of that to landscape A4 paper size, and assign that to the Report Viewer instance.

Here you go :

```
    Dim ps As New System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings()
    ps.Landscape = True
    ps.PaperSize = New System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("A4", 827, 1170)
    ReportViewer1.SetPageSettings(ps)
```